# Como interligar dois arrays?

Tags: php, array

Se eu tenho uma array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [color] => azul
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [color] => branca
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [color] => prata
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [color] => preta
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [color] => roxa
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [color] => vermelha
        )
)
```

E outra:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [COUNT(color)] => 3
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [COUNT(color)] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [COUNT(color)] => 1
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [COUNT(color)] => 6
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [COUNT(color)] => 1
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [COUNT(color)] => 6
        )
)
```

E quero interagir entre eles deixando os assim:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [color] => azul
            [COUNT(color)] => 3
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [color] => branca
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [color] => prata
            [COUNT(color)] => 3
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [color] => preta
            [COUNT(color)] => 3
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [color] => roxa
            [COUNT(color)] => 3
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [color] => vermelha
            [COUNT(color)] => 3
        )
)
```

Ou talvez de outra forma pois preciso usar ambos os valores em 1 foreach declarando, (nome da cor) e ao lado (quantidade).

Comment: Em php? qual linguagem?

Comment: Que linguagem seria essa?

Comment: Ah me esqueci de dizer PHP

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$x = Array(0 => Array('a' => 'b'), 1 => Array('c' => 'd'));
$y = Array(0 => Array('e' => 'f'), 1 => Array('g' => 'h'));

var_dump(array_map(array_merge, $x, $y));
?>
```

Saída:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(1) "b"
    ["e"]=>
    string(1) "f"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["c"]=>
    string(1) "d"
    ["g"]=>
    string(1) "h"
  }
}
```

O que a gente quer fazer com cada elemento dos arrays individuais é [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) (que combina as chaves de ambos os dicionários); [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) aplica `array_merge` a cada elemento de ambos os arrays individualmente e retorna a resposta.

Comment: ta me retornando isso:  " Notice: Use of undefined constant array_merge - assumed 'array_merge' "vou ver aqui o q pode ser

Comment: Você rodou exatamente o código que eu escrevi, ou você adaptou no seu código? Sabe dizer a versão do seu PHP?

Comment: Adaptei, mas da mesma forma que vc escreveu vem o mesmo erro. Coloquei apenas array_map(array_merge, $x, $y)