# PHP - Array - Chaves Verticais para Horizontais

Tags: php, array

#### Situação

Eu possuo um array da seguinte forma:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [tree] => Array
                (
                    [tb_agenda_hora] => 2,
                    [tb_agenda_fase] => 1,
                    [tb_agenda] => null
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tree] => Array
                (
                    [tb_prospeccao] => 1,
                    [tb_agenda] => null
                )
        )
)
```

#### Necessidade

Deseja deixa-lo assim :

```
Array
(
    [tb_agenda] => Array(
        [tb_agenda_fase] => Array(
            [tb_agenda_hora] => Array()
        ),
        [tb_prospeccao] => Array()
    )
)
```

Ou seja, minha ordem da chave `tree` é a ordem das chaves do `array`.

Alguem sabe como implementar isto?

Comment: [Relacionado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67408/como-interligar-dois-arrays/67411#67411), mas você vai precisar fazer isso pra cada nível da sua estrutura.

Comment: E como pretende manter os valores? Visando que agora tudo estará aninhado e arrays.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel, os valores não são importantes podem ser perdidos, servem apenas como auxiliar de ordenação. Ex.: a `chave` que tem como `value = null` é a pai de todas, a `chave = 1` é filha da anterior e assim por diante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom para resolver meu problema montei esta função, já faz um tempo apenas não a postei.
Ela trabalha com a ideia que quero, mas se limita apenas ao `array` monodimencional, ou seja se mais alguém quiser utilizá-la tera de adaptar.

```
function addArrayH(&$array, $value){
    if(is_array($array) && !empty($array)){
        foreach ($array as $k => $dados){
            if(is_array($dados) && !empty($dados)){
                addArrayH($array[$k], $value);
            }else{
                $array[$k] = $value;
            }
        }
    }else{
        $array = $value;
    }
}

# MONTA ARVORE DA SEQUENCIA
$tmp = array();
foreach($array as $k => $options){
    foreach (array_reverse($options['tree']) as $tableOrder => $fkOrder){
        $order = array($tableOrder => array());
        $this->addArrayH($tmp, $order);
    }
}
```

#### Mais Exemplo

```
$temp = array(
    'teste1' => array(
        'teste1.1' => array(
            'teste1.1.1'
        ),
    ),
    'teste2' => array(
        'teste2.1' => array(
            'teste1.2.1'
        ),
        'teste2.2' => array(
            'teste1.2.1'
        ),
    ),
    'teste3' => null,

);

$tmp = array();
foreach ($temp as $k => $value){
    $order = array($k => array());
    $this->addArrayH($tmp, $order);
}
```

#### Out

```
Array
(
    [teste1] => Array
        (
            [teste2] => Array
                (
                    [teste3] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```